# Can Greater Metamorphosis or Assume Supernatural Ability be used to acquire supernatural class features??

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, feats, psionics, shapeshifting

The ability to change into various forms using Greater Metamorphosis includes the assumption that when there are more than one creature of a particular race, they do NOT count as a unique individuals for the purpose of the power, or at least their collective average does not count. This also seems to apply to subtypes of a given race which are also valid targets.

It also allows one to gain all extraordinary and Supernatural special attacks and qualities of the creature.

Should there be a number of creatures that have a given base and/or prestige class, would that count both as non-unique and as an effective subtype of said race, or in any case making suoernatural class features (listed in the Special Attacks or Special Qualities in NPC start blocks) a valid target for Greater Metamorphosis and/or Assume Supernatural Ability?

Answer (score 4):

### Creatures with class levels are unique

[Greater Metamorphosis](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/metamorphosisGreater.htm) says:

> As metamorphosis, except that this power enables you to assume the form of any single **nonunique object or creature (of any type)**

[Assume Supernatural Ability](https://dnd.arkalseif.info/feats/savage-species--47/assume-supernatural-ability--133/index.html) says:

> You learn to use a single supernatural ability of another **kind of creature** while assuming its form

So, is an improved monster that has class levels still a generic type or kind of monster, or is it unique? The rules for [Improving Monsters](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm) say:

> Each of the monster entries describes a typical creature of its kind. However, there are several methods by which **extraordinary or unique monsters can be created** using a typical creature as the foundation: by adding character classes, increasing a monster’s Hit Dice, or by adding a template to a monster.

So, class levels (or templates, which are explictly exempt from Metamorphosis) turn a typical creature of its type into an *extraordinary or unique* creature. It is not a typcial creature any more, it is unique, an individual creature. Greater Metamorphosis or Assume Supernatural Ability do not apply to it or its expanded Supernatural Abilities.